# Instagram OAuthException : you must provide a client_id

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, https, instagram-api

I've been trying to use server side authentication of instagram API in my web app. I've followed the steps provided at [Intagram's API Page](https://www.instagram.com/developer/), but I keep getting the error `you must provide a client_id`. The code is written in node/express.js. Here is my code.
PS: Please don't suggest me to use istagram-node API. 
**index.js**

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var https = require('https');
var session = require('express-session');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));
app.use(session({
  secret: process.env.SECRET,
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: false
}))

app.set('port',process.env.PORT);

app.get('/',function(req,res){
  res.render('index')
});

app.get('/home',function(req,res){
  req.session.code = req.query.code;
  var data = JSON.stringify({
      client_id: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
      client_secret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
      grant_type: "authorizaton_code",
      redirect_uri: "...",
      code: req.session.code
  })
  var options = {
    headers:{
      'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
      hostname: 'api.instagram.com',
      path: '/oauth/access_token',
      method:'POST',
      port:443
    }
    var request = https.request(options,function(resp){
      resp.on('data',function(chunk){
        req.session.data = chunk.toString();
      })
    })
    request.write(data);
    request.end();
    setTimeout(function(){
      res.json(req.session.data)
    },5000);
})

app.listen(app.get('port'),function(){
  console.log("All eyes at "+process.env.PORT);
});
```

Comment: You did not specify the value of the client id and client secret. You can have a look at https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env. You can also consider using env2 library and store your environment variable in a .env instead of declaring it in JavaScript.

Comment: I'm using heroku to host the app. I've set the environment variable using `heroku config:set CLIENT_ID=...`. So, I can acces them using process.env. I get correct output when i run `heroku config:get CLEINT_ID`

Comment: Verify if "data" variable is correct or attach it to yours question.

Comment: [This](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/) is the official documentation of Instagram, I've followed the instructions and hopefully, I didn't miss out anything.

Answer (score 6):

Have been scratching my head all morning. it turns out you have to post it as form data.

add

```
   const FormData = require('form-data');
```

at the top
then your code is as follows:

```
  var data = new FormData();
  data.append('client_id',config.instagramAuth.client_id)
  data.append('client_secret',config.instagramAuth.client_secret)
  data.append('redirect_uri',redirect_uri)
  data.append('grant_type','authorization_code')
  data.append('code',code)
```

and your fetch:

```
  fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: data //JSON.stringify(postData)
      })
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Did you get "TypeError: str.replace is not a function" with this code?