# using async module in nodejs returns nothing in response

Tags: node.js, express, instagram, instagram-api, async.js

I'm trying to post to Instagram API to authenticate user, but I'm getting null value as response. Before using async, I used `setTimeout` but it returned the error `you must provide a client_id`. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41437884/instagram-oauthexception-you-must-provide-a-client-id) is my previous post regarding the error.
Here is my code:

```
app.get('/home',function(req,res){
  req.session.code = req.query.code;
  var data = querystring.stringify({
      client_id: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
      client_secret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
      grant_type: "authorizaton_code",
      redirect_uri: "...",
      code: req.session.code
  })
  var options = {
    headers:{
      'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
      hostname: 'api.instagram.com',
      path: '/oauth/access_token',
      method:'POST',
      port:443
    }
    req.session.data = '';
    async.waterfall([
      function(callback){
        var request = https.request(options,function(resp){
          resp.on('data',function(chunk){
            req.session.data = chunk.toString();
          })
        })
        request.write(data);
        request.end();
        callback(null,req.session.data);
      }
     ],function(err,results){
      res.json(req.session.data||results[0]);
     })
})
```

Comment: I think you should use 'callback(null,req.session.data);' in the "resp.on('end'.." section.

Comment: It worked, thanxx. But now it is throwing the response as I mentioned in the previous post. Please have a look and see if you can figure out whats wrong there.

Comment: Why did it work inside the resp.on('end') and not this way?

Comment: You should call callback only when you are sure all your tasks are finished. In your case you try to return the data before it is fully readed.