# Instagram API keeps returning "You must provide a valid client_secret and code" error

Tags: node.js, axios, google-cloud-functions, instagram-api

Inside google cloud function, I need to exchange code for a token using instagram API.

```
    const code = req.body.code;
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
      }
    };

    const prepReq = () => {
      return axios.post(
        "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token",
        qs.stringify({
          client_id: "my_insta_app_id",
          client_secret: "my_insta_secret",
          grant_type: "authorization_code",
          redirect_uri: `my_redirect_uri`,
          code: code
        }),
        config
      );
    };

    try {
      const response = await prepReq();
      if (response.data.access_token) {
        return res
          .status(200)
          .type("application/json")
          .send({
            success: true,
            access_token: response.data.access_token,
            user_id: response.data.user_id
          });
      } else {
        throw new Error(
          "Something went wrong during authorization. Please try again."
        );
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      return res
        .status(400)
        .type("application/json")
        .send({
          success: false,
          message: e.response.data.error_message
        });
    }
```

However, it still returns error:

```
data: {
    error_type: 'OAuthException',
    code: 400,
    error_message: 'You must provide a valid client_secret and code'
}
```

I checked my secrets and ids and it's correct. Also, the API returns success response when I'm testing it using Postman.

Also, I don't know why, but sometimes, but really like once in a hundred attempts, my function returns correct response.

// edit - posting the whole google function code. As it has changed the way I pass the data (found that as a solution in axios documentation, but it's also not working), I'm posting it separately:

```
exports.socialAuthorizationHandler = functionsRegion.https.onRequest(
  (req, res) => {
    cors(req, res, async () => {
      const code = req.body.code;
      const config = {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        }
      };

      const prms = new test.URLSearchParams({
          client_id: "my_insta_app_id",
          client_secret: "my_insta_secret",
          grant_type: "authorization_code",
          redirect_uri: `my_redirect_uri`,
          code: code
      });

      const prepReq = () => {
        return axios.post(
          "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token/",
          prms.toString(),
          config
        );
      };

      try {
        const response = await prepReq();
        if (response.data.access_token) {
          return res
            .status(200)
            .type("application/json")
            .send({
              success: true,
              access_token: response.data.access_token,
              user_id: response.data.user_id
            });
        } else {
          throw new Error(
            "Something went wrong during authorization. Please try again."
          );
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        return res
          .status(400)
          .type("application/json")
          .send({
            success: false,
            message: e.response.data.error_message
          });
      }
    });
  }
);
```

Comment: Can you share the **entire** code of your Cloud Function?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Hi Renaud. Sure, I edited the code with the whole Cloud Function code.

Comment: Have you seen this?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41437884/instagram-oauthexception-you-must-provide-a-client-id

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Yes. I walked through a lot of stack/github questions about the similar problems with oauth services inside nodejs. Also through the one you posted, and yes, I tried to pass that using FormData instance. Still the same problem. :(

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Also, the problem starts getting weird. Because sometimes, my request passes as expected, but I'm not able to reproduce the success behavior yet.

Comment: "Because sometimes, my request passes as expected," => This is exactly why I asked to see the entire code. If the life cycle of your Cloud Function (CF) is not correctly managed, you may encounter erratic behaviour like this. But at first sight your code is correct. The only think I would change is to remove the `return`s: don't do `return res.status(XXX)...` but just `res.status(XXX)...`. You should terminate HTTPS CF with `res.redirect()`, `res.send()`, or `res.end()`without return. I don't think, however, that it will change the CF behaviour.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec It seems that using `res.send()` instead of returning response (like you said) fixed my issue. However, I now need to test it more deeply; If that was the issue, then I will answer my question with the correct code. Thank you

Comment: Glad I could apparently helped you! I've written an answer along those lines. Please accept and upvote it after you have confirmed it solved your problem. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions), to terminate HTTP functions you need to call one of the following method on the `response` object: `redirect()`, `send()`, or `end()`.

So you don't need to return anything (as you would do for any background Cloud Function), just call one of these [Express.js](https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#res.send) methods.

So instead of doing:

```
exports.socialAuthorizationHandler = functionsRegion.https.onRequest(
    (req, res) => {
        cors(req, res, async () => {
            //...

            try {
                const response = await prepReq();
                if (response.data.access_token) {
                    return res
                        .status(200)
                        .type("application/json")
                        .send({
                            success: true,
                            access_token: response.data.access_token,
                            user_id: response.data.user_id
                        });
                } else {
                    // ...
                }
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
                return res
                    .status(400)
                    .type("application/json")
                    .send({
                        success: false,
                        message: e.response.data.error_message
                    });
            }
        });
    });
```

you should do

```
exports.socialAuthorizationHandler = functionsRegion.https.onRequest(
    (req, res) => {
        cors(req, res, async () => {
            //...

            try {
                const response = await prepReq();
                if (response.data.access_token) {
                    res
                        .status(200)
                        .type("application/json")
                        .send({
                            success: true,
                            access_token: response.data.access_token,
                            user_id: response.data.user_id
                        });
                } else {
                    // ...
                }
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
                res
                    .status(400)
                    .type("application/json")
                    .send({
                        success: false,
                        message: e.response.data.error_message
                    });
            }
        });
    });
```

As per you comment above, it seems that by correctly ending the Cloud Function, you don't encounter the previous problem.

Comment: And from changing libraries for creating the request (I thought the problem lives in request package - axios, https, request), that's the solution that worked. Didn't really know that problem will live in my corrupt lifecycle implementation of the Cloud Function. Thank you!